# *293 connect() failed (111:connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client 221.148.103.36, server;

Tags: django, nginx

when i try to test via postman, i get 502 bad gate error.

so i explored docker at aws ec2 server(and conducted 'sudo docker logs {containerId}), and found this error sentence.

```
[error] 20#20: *293 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client 221.148.103.36, server.
```

is there anyone how to fix this error?

maybe, i think its because of nginx.conf file problem.

```
upstream django_rest_framework_17th {
  server web:8000;
}

server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://django_rest_framework_17th;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /static/ {
    alias /home/app/web/static/;
  }

  location /media/ {
    alias /home/app/web/media/;
  }
}
```

this is my nginx.conf file.

plus, i'm doing project with django, pycharm.